Issue with Redirecting After Logout Using TanStack Query in React
I'm trying to implement user state management with tanstack query instead of using react context. Right now i can log in and im redirected successfuly to my home page. However when i logout i invalidate the 'user' query key but no redirect is happening. It seems the my route rerender before the query key is invalidated.
Here is my ProtectRoute function
const ProtectRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const { data: user, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user'],
    queryFn: profile, //fetching /profile and returning user data
    retry: false,
  })

  if (isLoading) return <div>...loading</div>

  return user ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/signin" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  )
}

Im calling it in my App.ts
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />

      <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
        <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Route>

      <Route element={<ProtectRoute />}>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/*" element={<Missing />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

Here is how i try to logout
const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: logout,  //fetching /logout and returning void
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['user'] })
      navigate('/signin', { replace: true })
    },
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
    mutation.mutate()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>logout</button>
    </div>
  )
}

Here is my SignIn component:
const SignIn = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const location = useLocation()
  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/'

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<SignInForm>({
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  })

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (payload: SignInPayload) => login(payload), //fetching /login and returning user data
    onSuccess: () => navigate(from, { replace: true }),
    onError: (error) => {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        const { data } = error.response?.data // response data
        const message = data ? data.error.message : 'Something went wrong'
        setError('root', { type: 'custom', message })
      }
    },
  })

  const onSubmit = (data: SignInForm) => {
    mutation.mutate(data)
  }

  return (
    <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       ...
    </div>
  )
}


What I have tried:
I already tried to await the queryClient.invalidateQueries with no success. I also believe it should work without manually navigating after the invalidation.
Expected Behavior:
When the logout is successful, the ProtectRoute component should redirect to the /signin page automatically once the user query is invalidated.
Actual Behavior:
No redirection is happening after logging out. It seems that my route re-renders before the query key is invalidated and the user state is reseted.

navigate('/signin', { replace: true }) in the success handler should have already navigated the user to "/signin" and since SignIn isn't rendered on a route nested under the ProtectRoute layout route component the useQuery hook in ProtectRoute isn't going to be run because the component unmounted. Can you [edit] to clarify the observed behavior. Perhaps you could try also creating a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Sorry for the unclear question. I already figured it out. I posted the solution in an answer.

The issue was that I misunderstood the invalidateQueries function. For some reason, I thought that it "resets" the state on the 'user' query key and makes it undefined or null.
Now I understand that on running invalidateQueries the specified queryFn reruns and saves the result as the state.
The error was in my 'profile' query function. It didn't return anything on a failed fetch attempt.
After a logout, I invalidate the authentication cookie and the next profile fetch will fail. I had to return a null so react query can update the state.
const { data:user } = useQuery<User | null>({
  queryKey: ['user'],
  querying: async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/auth/profile')
      return data.user
    } catch (error) {
      return null
    },
    retry: false,
  })

